# Exporting data escaping new lines not working

Tags: mysql, csv, escaping, export

I need to export data from a mysql table to a csv file.  Two fields in particular are giving me trouble.  Their data types are varchar and TEXT.

Data in these columns contain all sorts of gross characters, particularly new line (\n) and tabs (\t).  I need to export these into a .csv file for a migration.

Unfortunately, I cannot enclose the fields with '"' because the destination database doesn't support that formatting.

So, my query looks like the following:

```
SELECT `varchar_col`,`text_col` FROM `db`.`tbl`   INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/my/file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY "\\" LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

When I look at my output file (used gedit and nano), I simply see that each new line or tab in the file is preceded by a backslash (see example below).  I would like a new line or tab instead to read the literal chacters '\n' or '\t' instead of actual new lines and tabs.

Example of problem with new line-

field value of:

```
value one
value two
```

exported to .csv gives me:

```
value one\
value two\
```

instead of:

```
value 1\nvalue 2
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The CSV spec relies on double-quoting as an escaping mechanism. The fact that whomever is importing this data can't use this means one of you two is going to have to change technologies for transporting the data.

Comment: What database is the other party using? Maybe you can just do a plain SQL dump.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure. But is this what you want? (Output literal chacters '\n' or '\t' instead of actual new lines and tabs.)

```
SELECT * FROM block INTO OUTFILE '/var/tmp/d.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t' ESCAPED BY "\\" LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';
```

Comment: Not quite.  The value stored in the database is multiple lines.  When I export it, there are new lines in the generated csv file for that given stored value.  This is bad because each line the the csv ought to be a new row

Comment: so you want the new line in the value be escaped to literal "\n" too?

Comment: I solved the problem.  I was trying to import into HBase.  I used the sqoop command and ran a custom query to format the fields.  The trick was to use REPLACE(REPLACE(`col`,"\n","\\n"),"\t","\\t") in my select query   Worked great for what I was doing, but didn't solve the problem for exporting to csv